# Unable to read kafka stream in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

**kafka-python**: 2.0.2
**spark**:3.1.1

kafka-python is wrapper library for python to work with kafka. I have created a kafka stream against a topic in kafka using kafka-python producer. Following is the code to import initialize and send data for a topic.

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092')
producer.send(topic_name, str.encode(text+"\n"))
```

Now when i read this in kafka-python consumer i am able to read it without any error the code is below.

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
consumer = KafkaConsumer(
 topic_name,
 bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],
 auto_offset_reset='earliest',
 enable_auto_commit=True,
 value_deserializer=lambda x: x.decode('utf-8'))
for message in consumer:
   print(message)
```

This code gives all the massages for that topic from beginning. But when i try to read it in spark structure stream i am not getting anything it seems that the pyspark is not getting the stream from that topic.
The pyspark code is below.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("test").getOrCreate()
df = spark.readStream.format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "127.0.0.1:9092,localhost:9092") \
  .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
  .option("subscribe", topic_name) \
  .load()

 query = df.\
  writeStream.format("console").\
  trigger(processingTime='1 seconds').\
  option("checkpointLocation","path/to/checkpoints").\
  start()

 query.awaitTermination()
```

I have tried many different options for reading and writing stream but not working. So i just want to keep it simple to see if its possible.

Comment: Spark can read **and write** to Kafka. You do not need `kafka-python`. Ex. https://github.com/OneCricketeer/docker-stacks/blob/master/hadoop-spark/spark-notebooks/kafka-sql.ipynb

Comment: Another thing to check - are you able to consume with any other Kafka client? If not, the problem is your kafka installation, rather than Spark

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer i am using kafka-python for producer because i am reading the data from an application. I am good with spark read and write stream but i am using kafka-python first time.

Comment: If kafka topic has less partitions than number of consumers(in same consumer group) then some consumers stays idle. Can you check number of partitions and consumers for your topic.